# Execute all statements within try/catch

Tags: java, try-catch

I have a bunch of similar statements in a try block, and I want all of them to execute, even if some fail. It would look something like this:

```
try {
   doThing1();
   doThing2();
   doThing3();
   doThing4();
} catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

However, if `doThings2()` fails, for example, then 3 and 4 will not execute. How can I get all of them to execute? I'd rather not put each of them in its own try/catch block.

Comment: *I'd rather not put each of them in its own try/catch block.* Why not?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Mostly because I feel it would be ugly and a waste of space. If it's the only way, I guess that's what I'll do.

Comment: put them in finally

Comment: try {} catch() {} finally {}

Comment: @bakero98 If I put them in finally, they could cause the program to crash though, correct? I still need all of the errors to be caught.

Comment: @multitask: How should the exception handling look like if e.g.doThing2() and doThing4() throw an exception? How do you want to handle them in a single catch block? Or do you just want to ignore them?

Answer (score 4):

You could write a function that executes a set of invocations and that doesn't stop even if an exception is thrown :

```
public void doThing(Runnable... invocations){
      for (Runnable invocation : invocations){
         try{
                invocation.run()
           }
           catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println(e.getMessage());
           }
       } 
}
```

And use it in this way if the methods are located in the same class:

```
doThing( this::doThing1, this::doThing2, this::doThing3, this::doThing4);
```

Otherwise prefix the statement with the correct class/instance :

```
doThing( () -> foo.doThing1(),  () -> foo.doThing2(),  () -> foo.doThing3(),  () -> foo.doThing4());
```

Comment: Hello you. I leave you a start. I don't know if you know the Jean de La Fontaine fable "The Hare and the Tortoise". It is a french author (inspired by Esope) that does paraboles with animal stories. That fable illustrates well that : https://www.akg-images.fr/archive/Le-Lievre-et-la-Tortue-2UMDHUNBDRKW.html. :)

Comment: These are independent functions/procedures without side effects each one of them can through exception on its own while the others complete they are immutable therefore  fire and forget solution may be preferable.

Comment: @Alexandar Petrov It might be but in the present case I am not sure that introducing this API answers to the initial question. I try to avoid interpretation.

Comment: @davidxxx is immutability here a question of interpretation? Succeeding methods some of them failing with exception.

Answer (score 0):

Since each of the methods can fire an exception while the others complete we can assume that they do not lead to side effects In which case we can just fire and forget them without thinking about side effects.

```
ExecutionService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool();

service.submit(()->doThing1())
service.submit(()->doThing2())
service.submit(()->doThing3())
service.submit(()->doThing4())
```

Comment: It's correct but I hate this. Try catches may be more ugly but it's better than this monstrosity

Comment: @MatthewKerian well you asked for it :D

Comment: @Alexandar Petrov Why parallelism ? The processing may be dependent between them and so using threads don't make sense in the actual question. My answer diverges on this point that matters.

Comment: @davidxxx have I specified a number for my Executor service ? Not really I am just taming advantage of the fire and forget. Plus we can not really speculate what is inside the doThing method :)

Comment: @davidxxx I see that your solution is different I got confused by the Runnable interface .